Strange Errors in c# Windows Forms Project Involving a .csx file that doesn't even exist
I have a Windows Forms app I've been developing and all of a sudden two errors show up in my Errors List tab that are strange.
First, they don't prevent my app from compiling and running.
Next, they both reference a project (Submission#0) that doesn't exist in my solution and a file that exists nowhere on my system (Submission1.csx).
Aside from that they are unspectacular; one says that a ComboBox doesn't exist in the current context and the other says the type or namespace "Point" could not be found.
I've looked in the solution file; no reference to a Submission#0 project or anything unexpected.  And like I said, there is no file ANYWHERE on my system that is named Submission1.csx.
I'm stumped.  Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Been playing with View > Other Windows > C# Interactive?  Maybe deleting the suo file will help.

Wow @HansPassant!  I don't recall ever playing with C# Interactive, but removing the suo file cleared things up.  Thanks!!

The warning I got pointed to file "c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\community\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\vbcsharp\languageservices\InteractiveHost\Core\Submission3.csx" although I did not find it...

This mentions deleting bin/obj/.vs folder


Been playing with View > Other Windows > C# Interactive? Maybe
deleting the suo file will help. –  Hans Passant  CommentedAug 11 at
22:48

Mr Passant is correct.
The deleting suo file part in Visual Studio 2022 can be done by View > Other Windows > C# Interactive > Reset > Clean Screen. Which the last two steps can be found as buttons on the top left of the C# Interactive window.
(This worked for me so if you had trouble please report it)
